# How to assign an MSI installer property to an XSL variable?

Tags: xslt, wix

I have an MSI installer property `SQLSERVER_AUTHENTICATIONMODE`, which gets set in the installer UI (using a Wix Dialog). I have an XSLT in the Wix project that I use to transform an `File.xml` that is included in the installation. The type of transformation depends on the value of `SQLSERVER_AUTHENTICATIONMODE`, e.g.:

```
<xsl:variable name="sqlServerAuthenticationMode">[SQLSERVER_AUTHENTICATIONMODE]</xsl:variable>
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$sqlServerAuthenticationMode = 1">
        <util:XmlFile
            Id="UpdateConnectionString"
            Action="bulkSetValue"
            ElementPath="//ConnectionString"
            File="[INSTALLFOLDER]\File.xml"
            Value="Provider=SQLOLEDB;Server=[SQLSERVER_SERVERNAME];database=[SQLSERVER_DATABASENAME];Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <util:XmlFile
            Id="UpdateConnectionString"
            Action="bulkSetValue"
            ElementPath="//ConnectionString"
            File="[INSTALLFOLDER]\File.xml"
            Value="Provider=SQLOLEDB;Server=[SQLSERVER_SERVERNAME];database=[SQLSERVER_DATABASENAME];User Id=[SQLSERVER_USERNAME];Password=[SQLSERVER_PASSWORD];Persist Security Info=False;"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

The `xsl:variable` is not being set properly, because `$sqlServerAuthenticationMode = 1` is never true. For example, when `SQLSERVER_AUTHENTICATIONMODE` is 1, `$sqlServerAuthenticationMode` should be set to 1, but it is not.

Comment: I am not familiar with the use of XSLT and Wix but in general to pass external values to XSLT a global `xsl:param` is used, not a variable, so try to declare an `xsl:param` as a direct child of the `xsl:stylesheet/xsl:transform` root element of the XSLT code.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think that is the answer.  There are other installer properties in my sample code which work fine, but I do not have to declare them as params. The square brackets means their values will be used, but this does not work when assigning a variable.

Comment: why to use with XSL for that? You can use a Condition under component that contains util:XmlFile...

Answer (score 0):

Bit late to the party, but hopefully this will help someone.

Those MSI properties aren't assigned until runtime, the xsl:variable will be empty during compliation/pre-processing.

You could try a component & condition like this:

```
<Component Id="{@Id}_auth" Guid="*">
  <Condition><![CDATA[SQLSERVER_AUTHENTICATIONMODE = 1]]></Condition>
  <util:XmlFile
      Id="UpdateConnectionString"
      Action="bulkSetValue"
      ElementPath="//ConnectionString"
      File="[INSTALLFOLDER]\File.xml"
      Value="Provider=SQLOLEDB;Server=[SQLSERVER_SERVERNAME];database=[SQLSERVER_DATABASENAME];Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;"/>
</Component>

<Component Id="{@Id}_noauth" Guid="*">
  <Condition><![CDATA[SQLSERVER_AUTHENTICATIONMODE <> 1]]></Condition>
  <util:XmlFile
      Id="UpdateConnectionString"
      Action="bulkSetValue"
      ElementPath="//ConnectionString"
      File="[INSTALLFOLDER]\File.xml"
      Value="Provider=SQLOLEDB;Server=[SQLSERVER_SERVERNAME];database=[SQLSERVER_DATABASENAME];User Id=[SQLSERVER_USERNAME];Password=[SQLSERVER_PASSWORD];Persist Security Info=False;"/>
</Component>
```